# How to use the same iframe script with multiple sources?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, magnific-popup

First of all I'm a total noob so code might be harsh.

With that said, I have a page with several images (thumbnails) that I want to make clickable so that they enlarge and display their own embedded YouTube video. I use Magnific Pop-Up for the aesthetic of the whole thing.

I succeeded in doing exactly what I want but it obviously only works for one source, so I'd like to know what's the best way to have a unique script targetting several sources (depending on the clicked item)?

Here's an example (all sensitive values are redacted for privacy reasons):

```js
$('.container').on('click', function () {
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
            src: '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video-url" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
            type: 'iframe'
        }
    });
});
```

```html
                    <div class="container">
                        <img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt="Video 1">
                        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                    </div>
```

The iframe is in the script because otherwise it'd clearly display both the images and the embedded players in an unordoned manner, and I want the embedded player to stay hidden unless an image is clicked, only then the popup opens and display the YouTube player.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: Each image matches a single embedded video, on click it's not supposed to play a random video, only the corresponding one.

Comment: When clicked, you want to play any random video or multiple videos at once?

Comment: @Blind Spot I edited the post to state that each image matches a single embedded video, so not random, and only the corresponding video has to play when an image is clicked.

Comment: So you also need to create Multiple images too, right? If that's the case I have a javascript solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

For creating one image for one video and specific url, you also need a div for each of them.
Here, I have created an array of objects in javascript named `links`, which contains all the information about each video and It'll append that to the main div, `content`.

In simple words:

1. I created an array named `links` which contains objects, with information about each video:

```js
var links = [{
      thumbnail: "thumbnail.jpg",
      url: "url",
      alt: "alt"
    }, {
      thumbnail: "thumbnail2",
      url: "url2",
      alt: "alt2"
    }]
```

2. I created a parent div, which'll contain all images, `<div id="content"></div>`.
3. Using `for loop` and jquery(`.append` property), I added elements in parent div with unique Id for each, to access it later:

```js
//access each element of links array one by one
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

//"id=${i}" is unique id for each div, it also matches with specific element in array.
//For ex: 2nd element of array will get "id=1"...
  $('#content').append(`<div class="container" id="${i}">
    <img src="${links[i].thumbnail}" alt="${links[i].alt}">
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>`);
}
```

4. Whenever any element with "container" class is clicked, it'll get the id of the element using `var id = $(this).attr('id');` and open link using "magnificpopup" for the div of specific Id:

```js
$.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
          src: `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="${links[id].url}" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`,
          type: 'iframe'
        }
      });
```

**Note:** Here, `links[id].url` is url of element with specific Id, which we had assigned to each element while creating it in step 3. Since, we had assigned the Id according to the number of element, like 2nd element as id 1, we directly accessed it here using its position in array.

5. Final code:

   ```js
   var links = [{
     thumbnail: "thumbnail.jpg",
     url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/video-url-1",
     alt: "Video 1"
   }, {
     thumbnail: "thumbnail-2.jpg",
     url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/video-url-2",
     alt: "Video 2"
   }, {
     thumbnail: "thumbnail-3.jpg",
     url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/video-url-3",
     alt: "Video 3"
   }]

   for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
     $('#content').append(`<div class="container" id="${i}">
       <img src="${links[i].thumbnail}" alt="${links[i].alt}">
       <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
         <div class="overlay"></div>
     </div>`);
   }

   $('.container').on('click', function() {
     var id = $(this).attr('id');

     $.magnificPopup.open({
       items: {
         src: `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="${links[id].url}" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`,
         type: 'iframe'
       }
     });
   });
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div id="content"></div>
   ```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the extensive answer! I'll try to cherry-pick what I need in your code, as the images are already created and organized as I wish I only need them to point to the right url.

Comment: glad to hear that, if this didn't solved your problem you can suggest me what to edit in my answer to mark it as answer or post your own answer, this'll also help others.